# Flash Professional Error 2006

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have looked over this and I must be blind as I cannot see what the problem is. I looked a bit online and tried to modify it to work, but no luck.

```
function dragTheObject(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target); 
    item.startDrag();
    var topPos:uint = (item, numChildren > 0 ? numChildren-1 : 0); 
    this.parent.setChildIndex(item, topPos);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AS3 #2006 runtime error ( `RangeError: Error #2006: The Supplied Index is Out of Bounds` ) is fired by this line :

```
this.parent.setChildIndex(item, topPos);
```

because your trying to set an index to your `item` object which is greater than (or equal to) the `DisplayObjectContainer`'s (`this.parent`) `numChildren` property.

So to put your object on the top, you can simply do :

```
function dragTheObject(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);
        item.startDrag();

    item.parent.setChildIndex(item, item.parent.numChildren - 1);
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: that is a lot of unnecessary code for what is simply a more complicated way to do "addChild". You could also explain that the sequence: "(item, numChildren > 0 ? numChildren-1 : 0);" can't work because in that case "numChildren" refers to the current DisplayObject, not to the item.parent object (item.parent.numChildren should be used)